# Can't load gem from local path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler

I'm [creating an azure wrapper](https://github.com/meloncargo/dragonfly-azure_data_store) for [dragonfly](https://github.com/markevans/dragonfly) gem and I've published it in [rubygems](https://rubygems.org/gems/dragonfly-azure_data_store). Now I'm loading it in the `Gemfile` of my rails app with:

```
gem 'dragonfly-azure_data_store',
    git: 'https://github.com/meloncargo/dragonfly-azure_data_store.git',
    branch: :master
```

and the gem loads, but as I'm changing it constantly, I've configured bundler to load directly from my path:

```
bundle config local.dragonfly-azure_data_store /home/alter/workspace/meloncargo/dragonfly-azure_data_store
```

and when I start the rails app, it throws:

> /home/alter/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2@productwatcher/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in
>   `require': cannot load such file -- dragonfly-azure_data_store
>   (LoadError)

I've tried setting the gem as a path, without the bundler config:

```
gem 'dragonfly-azure_data_store',
    path: '/home/alter/workspace/meloncargo/dragonfly-azure_data_store'
```

But I receive the same error. Just for the record, my local gem has the same changes as in master and any change I made locally (example: adding  `puts 'foo'` inside `def initialize` of the main class), is reflected when I started the rails app, but eventually the error is raised.
Any idea what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just realized the problem has to do with I'm using [`require_reloader`](https://github.com/teohm/require_reloader) gem .
I've created [an issue](https://github.com/teohm/require_reloader/issues/9) to see what happens with it.

Answer (score 0):

Using a relative path for the argument should work

```
gem 'dragonfly-azure_data_store', path: '../dragonfly-azure_data_store'
```

And in your ruby file:

```
require 'dragonfly'
require 'dragonfly/azure_data_store'
```

Comment: That didn't work. The problem is not the path isn't being loaded, but the error is raised despite the gem is being loaded locally.

Comment: I see I was able to do this with a file requiring like:

    require 'dragonfly'
    require 'dragonfly/azure_data_store'